# How can I convert string to array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to convert this string :

this is the codeigniter controller:

```
function getUsersFromProjects(){
    $projectID = $_POST['projectID'];
    $data = $this->tasks->getUserIdFromProjects($projectID);
    var_dump($data);
}

array(12) {  [0]=>  string(13) "AAAAA"  
             [1]=>  string(13) "BBBBB"  
             [2]=>  string(12) "CCCCC"  
             [3]=>  string(11) "DDDDD"  
             [4]=>  string(10) "EEEEE"  
             [5]=>  string(13) "FFFFF"  
             [6]=>  string(10) "GGGGG"  
             [7]=>  string(13) "HHHHH"  
             [8]=>  string(9) "IIIIIII"  
             [9]=>  string(9) "IIIIIII"  
             [10]=>  string(15) "TTTTTTTT"  
             [11]=>  string(12) "XXXXXXXX"
         }
```

this is the js file :

```
$.post('/taskuri/getUsersFromProjects/', { projectID: projectIdRow }, function(data){
    callback(data);
});
```

and the callback function:

```
function callback(data){
        $('.idUser').val(data);
        $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
            value: 1,
            text: 'tralala'
        }));
}
```

I want to populate my dropdowns with the elements from the array . How can i do that?

Comment: that's a var dump of a array....

Comment: JSON encode it and then parse it.

Comment: Please post code in proper way. Its look like very ugly. post your code here. not a dump array

Comment: @GertB. What if the dump **is** the string?

Comment: you could probably write a complicated RegEx for that but as @GertB. already said. It's a var dump of an array. A more elegant solution would be to get your array in a proper format (like JSON).

Comment: I know, but i need to make from this string an array. how can i do that?

Comment: @BlackSheep can you make me an example ?

Comment: There are many examples in [here](http://ir1.php.net/json_encode).

Comment: @Chester, if it's not something you will need to do repeatedly in an automated way, if it's a one go operation.... I'll suggest you just write that array manually, it will save you a lot of time. If it's for the sake of learning you should use a more generic question I guess

Comment: XY Problem.  Without more information we may well just be leading you further into a quagmire.  (Giggety)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your array dump doesn't look like user ids...but i suppose "Adrian Ilovan...Cristi Cojita" its your user ID

```
function getUsersFromProjects(){
    $projectID = $_POST['projectID'];
    $data = $this->tasks->getUserIdFromProjects($projectID);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function callback(data){
        $('.idUser').val(data);
        var jsondatas = JSON.parse(data);
        for(i=0;i < jsondatas.length ; i++)
        {
            jsondata = jsondatas[i];
            $('#mySelect').append("<option value='" + jsondata  + "'>" + jsondata + "</option>"); 
        }

}
```